# How to close an HTTP connection?

Tags: angular, http

I have this code:

```
this.http.get(url)
.subscribe(
  data => {

  },
  error=>{

  }
)
```

How I can close an HTTP connection?

Comment: what do you mean by close?

Comment: @Keerthi, the connection is open, but implicitly. See my answer

Comment: My bad. Thanks for pointing it out. Deleting the wrong comment.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're talking about the analogue to something like it's done in Java:

```
//Create connection
URL url = new URL(targetURL);
connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
...
connection.disconnect();
```

then you don't need to do that. Angular uses [XHR browser API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest) to make HTTP requests. This API doesn't require explicitly opening or closing the connection, it does so automatically once the request is sent and response obtained or the timeout exceeded.

Also, you don't need to explicitly unsubscribe from the observable since the observable returned by the `this.http.get` completes by itself. Here is the relevant sources:

```
export class XHRConnection implements Connection {
    ...
    response: Observable<Response>;
    constructor(req: Request, browserXHR: BrowserXhr, baseResponseOptions?: ResponseOptions) {
        this.request = req;
        this.response = new Observable<Response>((responseObserver: Observer<Response>) => {
            ...
            // load event handler
            const onLoad = () => {
                ...
                const response = new Response(responseOptions);
                response.ok = isSuccess(status);
                if (response.ok) {
                    responseObserver.next(response);
                    responseObserver.complete();  <--------------------
                    return;
                }
                responseObserver.error(response);
            };
```

The observable created inside `XHRConnection` is the observable you receive when you do `http.get()`.